# Handle different kinds of json on the same route with vapor 3

Tags: swift, rest, vapor

I'm trying to add a POST endpoint on my **Vapor 3** server to create a new resource, but I want to have 3 different JSON formats that can create that resource. So I have 3 different `Content` structs that are each fairly similar.

```
struct IDJson: Content, DeckConvertible {
    var name: String?
    var format: Int
    var hero: Int
    var cards: [Int]
}

struct NameJson: Content, DeckConvertible  {
    var name: String?
    var format: Int
    var hero: String
    var cards: [String]
}

struct DeckstringJson: Content, DeckConvertible  {
    var name: String?
    var deckstring: String
}
```

And I would like to add them all to my router like this

```
class DeckRouteController: RouteCollection {
    func boot(router: Router) throws {
        router.post(IDJson.self, at: "user", "collection", use: createDeckHandler)
        router.post(NameJson.self, at: "user", "collection", use: createDeckHandler)
        router.post(DeckstringJson.self, at: "user", "collection", use: createDeckHandler)
    }
}
...

private extension DeckRouteController {
    func createDeckHandler(_ request: Request, container: DeckConvertible) throws -> Future<Response> {
        // Create deck
    }
}
```

Is this possible? at the moment only the last one gets used but is there a way I can do this with some middleware handler or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the decoding in the function itself, ie:

```
router.post("user", "collection", use: createDeckHandler)

func createDeckHandler(_ request: Request) throws -> String {
  let asId = try? request.content.syncDecode(IDJson.self)
  let asName = try? request.content.syncDecode(NameJson.self)
  if let asId = asId {
    // do stuff
  } else if let asName = asName {
    // do something else
  }
}
```